# Auto refresh on Page Cannot Be Displayed

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a site which auto-refreshes based on the meta data tag.
The problem is that sometimes I get the Page cannot be displayed in IE11.

Of course when that happens the refreshes also stop as the page did not load.

Is there a setting or IE add-on which can tell if the response is Page cannot be displayed and simply do a refresh automatically?